# Build System for typescript in sublime text 3 is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, sublimetext3

I have installed Sublime Text 3 and trying to create the build system for TypeScript. Below are the code I am using

```
{
    "cmd": ["tsc","$file"],
    "file_regex": "(.*\\.ts?)\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)\\)\\:\\s(...*?)$",
    "selector": "source.ts",

    "windows": {
        "cmd": ["tsc.cmd", "$file"]
    }
}

{
    "cmd": ["tsc", "-d", "-m", "amd", "--sourcemap", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "(.*\\.ts?)\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)\\)\\:\\s(...*?)$",
    "selector": "source.ts",
    "osx": {
       "path": "/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin"
    },
    "windows": {
        "cmd": ["tsc", "-d", "-m", "amd", "--sourcemap", "$file"]
    }
}
```

Getting [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
I tried both the Build System unable to generate the Corresponding JavaScript file. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The location of `tsc` needs to be on your system `PATH`.

Comment: Did you save your TypeScript code before trying to build?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still trying to figure this out, this is all I needed. The thing that really got me was that I needed to use `tsc.cmd` instead of just `tsc`. The `quiet:true` just removes the `[Finished in 1.6s]` that always shows at the bottom of the output window.

TypeScript converts the file to javascript and then the javascript file has to be run so...

- Make sure you've installed node js and `node` is in your path.
- Make sure you've installed TypeScript with `npm install -g typescript` (the node package manager) and `tsc` is in your path.

```
{
    "cmd": ["tsc.cmd", "$file_base_name.ts", "&&", "node", "$file_base_name.js"],
    "selector": "source.ts, source.tsx",
    "quiet": true
}
```